# how to Change f:param value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jsf

I want to change the f:param value attribute from javascript before submitting
suppose I have a jsf form

I have a link, which is only used to call the javascript function and passes the required parameter

```
<h:outputLink id="delete" value="#"
 onclick="confirmDelete('#{propertyObj.id}')"
 styleClass="btn btn-danger btn-xs">
 <h:outputText value="delete" />
</h:outputLink>
```

the javascript function is

```
function confirmDelete(propertyId) {
    var options = {
        "backdrop" : "static"
    }
    $('#confirm-delete').modal('show');
// I want to set the f:param value to propertyId here

}
```

the modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="confirm-delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
        aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
...
    <h:form id="modal-form">
    <h:commandLink id="delete" action="#{propertyBean.delete}"
        styleClass="btn btn-xs btn-red  arabic">
        <span class="fa fa-ban"></span> delete
    <f:param id="param" name="propertyId" value="???"/>//set value as passed from the javascript function
    </h:commandLink>
    </h:form>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('f\\:param').attr('value', 'something')`

Comment: What is the relationship between the first and last code snippets? You can easily pass a row identifier (`id` to delete a row as may be guessed at a glance) as a hidden field, if you want to show a confirm dialog before a row may be deleted.